# Is there a Stack Exchange site for voting methods, like STV, etc.?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've had a cursory glance, and I can't see anything appropriate. The closest one I found was *[Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour)*, but it doesn't seem to have any posts about the actual voting methods, not just the statistics involved.

I did find [Voting Systems](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97790/voting-systems) on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq). Is there anything else I've missed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Is there anything else I've missed?

You could try [Politics beta](https://politics.stackexchange.com/).

They have a [voting-systems](/questions/tagged/voting-systems) tag (currently 69 questions):

> For questions about rule systems for gathering and counting votes. Not for questions about country-specific rules but for the theory and practice of voting systems. Examples include proportional-representation and first-past-the-post.

This suggests questions about STV would be on topic.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Community Building](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/), if your question is about voting systems in the context of community management, like the voting behaviors that different systems encourage/discourage and how that affects a community making decisions.  There are tags for [voting](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting) and [moderator-elections](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderators).